# Better alternative for "even after"?

Tags: expressions, legalese

I have the following sentence in a legal document:

> The terms shall remain in force even after the Warranty obligation, as specified in article 1, ends.

Is there a better way of expressing "even after"?  To me, it sounds informal.

Edit: Added "legal" tag.

Comment: "To me, it sounds informal." Don't worry. It's not.

Comment: @ErikKowal - You're right, I really should have asked "Does this sound informal" rather than assume it did.

Comment: A comma after _force_, bracketing the "even after" phrase, will help. You might also consider deleting the one before the _as specified_ phrase, to pin that down to "even after".

Comment: Like this: `The terms shall remain in force, even after the Warranty obligation as specified in article 1, ends.`  Yes, better, thank you.

Comment: It would read just fine without the _even_.

Comment: @Frank - True, but this is a translation and the original text contains "even" and I have to stay true to the original.

Comment: Sabuncu: You're quite free to express personal opinions. It's the people who make rules out of them (or find someone else who has done to quote) one has to beware.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I exercise some amount of license as a translator and there have been many instances when I did not adhere to the original verbatim, but in this case, I feel I need to preserve "even", because what is being described is a so-called "latent defect".

Comment: I meant your 'I really should have asked "Does this sound informal" rather than assume it did' sounds unnecessarily contrite. Though asking the opinions of others is often best. But that doesn't mean the majority is always right. Although ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes, I am on pins and needles, because of my experience w/ StackOverflow.  That site is extremely useful, but I would not necessarily call it a "friendly" site.  (In fact, it is downright difficult.) Since this site is of the same family, I am being very cautious.  ;-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I like the phrase "unnecessarily contrite".  This is why I like asking questions here.  You ask about something, but in the process, you get more than just the answer to your original question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The terms shall remain in force, even *after the Warranty obligation specified in article 1 ends/expires.*

As an alternative, consider:

> The terms shall remain in force, even *beyond/past/after* the termination of the Warranty obligation specified in article 1.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think "past" works in this case.

Comment: @Sabuncu How about "beyond?"

Comment: It's not the word by itself that is problematic - the "ends" part at the end of the sentence is causing the problem.  "After the warranty ends" makes sense, but "Past/Beyond the warranty ends" does not.

Comment: @Sabuncu Actually, your sentence would sound a lot more natural if rephrased as follows: "...even after the Warranty warranty ends, as specified in..."

Comment: That would imply that article 1 specifies the end of the warranty obligation, rather than the warranty obligation itself.

Comment: I agree w/ @JanusBahsJacquet.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I wouldn't have understood it that way reading it. Anyways, I changed the phrase to make it less ambiguous on that point.

Comment: @Sabuncu How do you like it now it's been rephrased?

Comment: Now it says article one specifies that the terms remain in force after the Warranty obligation ends. Article 1 is meant to specify what the Warranty obligation is; nothing else.

Comment: Again, I concur w/ @JanusBahsJacquet.

Comment: @Sabuncu I just rephrased accordingly, dropping the "as."

Comment: You are tenacious!

Answer (score 0):

The terms shall survive the termination of the Warranty obligation specified in article 1.

Comment: "Termination" implies ending of the warranty before the contracted time.  Your structure is good but "expiry" would be a better word than "termination" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

We shouldn't answer. You actually need legal advice about the appropriate way to express this in your jurisdiction, not style advice about the way the diction or syntax flows.

The intention that seems so clear to you may be rendered ambiguous when it's constructed later in a court proceeding. Or you may be changing a jargon term of art with a specific meaning into a non-standard colloquialism that has not been tested in court.

Answer (score -1):

The terms shall remain in force even if the warranty obligation, as specified in article 1, ends.- This sounds rather formal.

Comment: But it rather significantly changes the phrasing. _After_ and _if_ do not mean the same thing, which in a legal text could be quite important.

Comment: The fact that the obligation shall end is a given.  Your proposal changes the original meaning while still using "even".

Comment: I hurt. I realize how stupid my answer was.